# "InvalidInput" error in azure datastore while inserting entity operation using REST implementation

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, azure-storage

I am using REST implmentation for azure Datastore instead of "azure-storage" SDK, while inserting entity in datastore table,i am getting below error,

[image]

**and statuscode return here is 400.**

I referred this documentation [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) and everything(like Authorization using hashmac, timestamp, header, json body etc) is formed correctly as per my understanding, but seems its not working, however same header and json body i have been passed through postman and its worked. Now question is here through REST why its not inserting entity in datastore table.
**Azure-Datastore version used: 2016-05-31**.

**REST API implementation: using nodejs/typescript.**

anybody have found this issue ever before and did know the possible root cause and solution.

Comment: 400 error usually means there's an issue with the data you're sending. Can you please edit your question and include the request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code's meaning can be found in [CommonRestApiErrorCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes) and [TableServiceErrorCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes).

As your description, the error would be:
**InvalidInput** Bad Request (400) One of the request inputs is not valid.

To trouble shoot the issue which input is invalid, please try to use tools like fiddler, catch the request sent by your tool, and:

- Share the request body for discussion.
- Or compare what's sent by azure-storage library, and find where is the problem.

BTW, Would you please share your concern on using Azure storage node client library?

Best Wishes

Comment: thank you for information. found the problem. It was in json body that i am forming. Now i have parsed the JSON body. It is working fine now. Below is my request body formation, `const body = JSON.stringify({
      'PartitionKey': entity.ParitionKey,
      'RowKey': entity.RowKey
    });`                                                                                                                                           and in request body, like as  `'body': JSON.parse(body),`